# How to Calculate values for inactive relationship with top N and calculate without Unpivoting

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two data bases.One contain carder and other one contain data.What I want is once I select the designation from the slicer.Then select the the employee and need to show higher defect rate styles.I have set little slicer to select higher 1 ,2 ,3 defect rate styles. .My measures as below.

```
Total Check = SUM(Records[Check Qty])
Total Defects = SUM(Records[Defects])
Selected_Top_N = SELECTEDVALUE('Top N'[Column1])
Defect pct = CALCULATE((DIVIDE([Total Defects],[Total Check])),TOPN([Selected_Top_N],ALL(Records[Style]),DIVIDE([Total Defects],[Total Check]),DESC),VALUES(Records[Style]))
```

This "Defect pct" measure works fine for Executive grade. Because it has active relationship. For qc it shows blank. My question is how to modify "Defect pct" measure using "userrelationship" or any other dax function to see top styles once I clicked qc from designation slicer and qc from the employee list.Without unpivoting I can get check qty and defect qty like below with %.by selected value for designation.'code'

```
Selected_designation = SELECTEDVALUE(Carder[Desingation])
SWITCH(true(),[selected_designation] ="Executive",DIVIDE([Total Defects],[Total Check]),
                            [selected_designation] ="QC",CALCULATE(DIVIDE([Total Defects],[Total Check]),USERELATIONSHIP(Records[QC],Carder[EMPLOYEE])))
```

'then using switch function I get these with two calulations.one for the direct relation ship.and other calculation with userrelationship for inactive one.I want rank this % with topN.End result must be once I click excetive I want rank higher defect % pct according to the selected executive and once I click qc I want the same.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l57W.jpg]

Comment: check for [TREATAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/treatas-function)

Comment: can you  modify the measure please

Comment: did you try unpivot in power query and then create only one relationship ?  

``#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(Source, {"QC", "Executive"}, "Attribute", "Value")``

Comment: I want to approach this using a dax measure.using userrelationship or etc.not with the power query

Comment: Hi @Karen. According to which columns are you trying to build the relationships? I mean join columns ? Please specify them.

Comment: carder table employee column to executive column in record table.This is the active relationship.This works fine.I get correct values.what I want to fix is carder table-employee column to qc column in record table.this is the inactive one.Please refer the image i have uploaded.I want calculate and rank the style depend on defect % same as for executive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to convert your fact table into this shape using unpivoting the last 2 columns.

Like This:

[image: FRS]

Then Create a designation Table consisting of 2 columns:
Like This:

[image: Designation]

Your Final Model View should appear like this:

[image: Karen_image]

(Updated) DAX Code For Defect pct:

```
Defect pct =
VAR selection =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Carder[Desingation] )
VAR conditional_selection =
    SWITCH (
        selection,
        "Executive", CALCULATE ( MAXX ( Records, DIVIDE ( [Total Defects], [Total Check] ) ) ),
        "QC",
            CALCULATE (
                MAXX ( Records, DIVIDE ( [Total Defects], [Total Check] ) ),
                USERELATIONSHIP ( Records[QC], Carder[EMPLOYEE] )
            )
    )
RETURN
    conditional_selection
```

Comment: If I do that its not possible to set slicer to filter employees by selecting designation form designation slicer. I have managers too.If it so I have to maintain carder list in different different tables.so not possible to change carder table.

Comment: @Karen Please check my updated solution.

Comment: I want dax measure modification.if I can get check qty and defect qty for qc Why we cant rank %.I updated my question with measures.

Comment: @Karen I added the DAX measure [Defect pct] for your request in the bottom part of my answer above. Please test it.